# Jquery, add value to array in each loop

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms, submit

I have a jQuery app where the user can add items to a list from an input field.
I want to put all items in an array when you submit the form so I can manipulate them with php later. Is this the right way to do it?

jQuery:

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
   var items = [];
   $("#items li").each(function(n){
      items[n] = $(this).html();
   });
   $.post(
      "process.php", 
      {items: items}, 
      function(data){
          $("#result").html(data);
      });
});
```

PHP:

```
$items = $_POST["items"];
foreach($items as $item){
    //Something here
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The idea is sound. What it not very clear is that your example populates `items` now, but the `submit` handler will of course be called at some point in the future. Is it possible that the list items may have changed by that time?

If so, you need to move the "pack the items" code inside the `submit` handler, e.g.:

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
    var items = [];
    $("#items li").each(function(n){
        items[n] = $(this).html();
    });

   $.post(
      "process.php", 
      {items: items}, 
      function(data){
          $("#result").html(data);
      });
});
```

Comment: Yeah! I made a mistake, I actually have it inside the submit function in my original code. It's corrected now. I just wanted to know if this is the most efficient way to deal with it. I'm pretty new to jquery and php.